# Sending customized Facebook message using Graph API for inviting friends to a website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send  message/notification to friends with customized subject with a link in it via Graph API. The link should redirect the friend to a particular website not to the application used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Javascript or PHP to interact with facebook? 
Either way you are going to want to use the 'link' parameter in the post.
Here is a php example which also posts a picture. If you need a Javascript example let me know.
Hope this helps!

```
$attachment = array(
'message' => $customMessage,
'link' => $MY_LINK_HERE,
'source' => $source,
'name' => $blogTitle,
'picture' => $picture,
'caption' => 'caption of the link',
'description' => ''
);
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed?access_token='.$access, 'post', $attachment);
```